# Is there any comparable (source-based) package management system like ABS on Arch Linux for Ubuntu?

Tags: .desktop

Is there anything comparable out there like the ABS on Arch Linux for Ubuntu?

I searched the web and the "most close" IMHO would be `flatpaks` as they can be interdependent? Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Flatpak/Snaps can be interdependent. But they are not source based. I would dare to say that even apt goes more in the direction of ABS than flatpak or snap.

Comment: I want to add: I really like Ubuntu, however I also like software from source like in the `ABS` or BSD-style `ports` - would be great if there is some strategy for Ubuntu which is feasible because I'm running Ubuntu (in different flavors) on four Desktops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABS follows many practices pioneered by Debian over 20 years ago.

See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html for the source build process in Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu).

---

Folks who enjoy building-from-source can benefit of the whole community. Consider volunteering to be a Debian Package Maintainer. That means you adopt a package (or a dozen) and rebuild it as new source versions and patches appear upstream. Debian (and Ubuntu) are based upon the efforts of these vital volunteers. Start your journey at http://mentors.debian.net.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. What does AUR stand for? And how can I browse these packages and install in Ubuntu?

Comment: You browse *source packages* using apt. You are not limited to source packages. Different types of sources have different methods to build. ALL methods involve the intermediate step of building from whatever source to a binary (.deb) package, then installing that binary package.

Comment: I see, now I feel completely retarded, totally missed this fact. Thanks!